# Where did /etc/init.d/dovecot go in 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, dovecot

I'm trying to configure dovecot+postfix on a new 14.04 release image in EC2. I installed mail-stack-delivery without installing postfix or dovecot separately. Now I can't figure out how to restart dovecot because /etc/init.d/dovecot seems missing.  Or am I missing something?  Thanks.

Comment: `sudo service dovecot restart` might work.

Comment: Thanks!  I actually did "sudo service --status-all" but dovecot wasn't on the list, and then "sudo service dovecot" returns "dovecot: unrecognized service", which made me believe dovecot wasn't converted to a service yet. So I never thought of actually trying with restart.

Comment: Is Dovecot installed? If it were, `service status dovecot` should return a `stopped/waiting` status.

Comment: @jingx you should better write your comment in an answer to this question and accept it.

Comment: The answer is there is no /etc/init.d/dovecot by default, but you can download a functional init.d script that should meet your needs at: http://wiki2.dovecot.org/RunningDovecot I recommend the wiki as a whole as a good resource for helping you with dovecot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @douggro for the reminder! I actually did `sudo service --status-all` but dovecot wasn't on the list, and then `sudo service dovecot` returns `dovecot: unrecognized service`, which made me believe dovecot wasn't converted to a service yet. So I never thought of actually trying with restart.

Comment: huh?  so what's the answer here?

Comment: Reviewers: While this technically does not clearly answer the question, for historical reasons it will be left here.

Answer (score 12):

Ok so after going through dovecot's wiki (version 2), it seems that we can restart/reload/stop dovecot by using:

For root:

`# doveadm reload` - to restart/reload dovecat

`# doveadm stop` - to stop dovecat

For sudo users:

`# sudo doveadm reload` - to restart/reload dovecat

`# sudo doveadm stop` - to stop dovecat

You can just type `doveadm` / `sudo doveadm` to see a list of other commands you can use with doveadm too.

Comment: Thanks for the real answer.
Why did they do this for? Just break the standard to make our lives harder? lol

Comment: @Zv_oDD The struggle is real haha

Answer (score 2):

When the old services are converted from init.d to the [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/), `service status xxxx` returns service unrecognized. Instead please use `servicename status`

The coexistence of upstart and init.d is confusing, so in Vivid and later releases it is replaced with [systemd](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers)

The current state in 14.04 is confusing and creating some issues when monitoring things as well, at least with my experience.